# Disable all the checkboxlist items if one of the particular item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist. which has three items

1. Male 
   2.Female
   3.Unknown

if someone selected Unknown then it should disable the other selection on the checkboxlist. if Unknown is selected then nothing can be selected. 
Any j query, java-script, c# code helps please...

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
$('.optionBox input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var $x= $('.optionBox input:checkbox'); 
    if($(this).is(':checked')){ 
       $x.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
    }
    else
    {
     .....
    }
})
```

Comment: this is a checkboxlist and all three items are list items with in this checkboxlist. so i am not sure where should i say that the item is checked with in the code above...as your code ran it it will diasable when anyone is selected but i need to check which item is selected. if that particular item is selected i disable all the items in same checkbox list. this is not checkboxes but a single checkboxlist with items.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code in jquery to handle this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#unknown").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
           $("#male, #female").attr('disabled','disabled');
        else
           $("#male, #female").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
    });
});
```

Here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/nKdJg/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/m8Leu/

```
// store the inputs and bind the change event
var $inputs = $( ".chkGroup input" );
$inputs.on( "change" , function(e) {

  // store the item that changed and the ones that didnt.
  var $changed = $(e.target);
  var $others = $inputs.not( $changed );

  // if the item that changed is "unknown"
  if( $changed.hasClass( "unique" ) ) {

    // save the state of the "unknown" chk
    // and set the other chks to it's state
    var state = $changed.prop( "checked" )    
    $others.prop( "disabled", state );

    // for good measure, we'll uncheck the
    // others because they are disabled
    if( state ) {
      $others.prop( "checked" , false );
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: <asp:checkboxlist id="SexDetermination" runat="server">
<asp:listitem>Male</asp:listitem>
<asp:listitem>Female</asp:listitem>
<asp:listitem>Unknown</asp:listitem>
</asp:checkboxlist>
Now here if i select male or female or both it is fine i don't need to disable. But if a user selected Unknown then other options should be disabled.
@ashish what is this means in your code you are passing the current item, so what ever is selected then the whole control will be disabled. which is wrong i am looking to disable only when unknown is selected.